# JQuery validator works just after first submit - asp .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I have an issue with JQuery validator. Validation start works just if I press submit button firstly. But I want make submit just if form valid. And I don't know why validation fields form after it as well. Please see my comments in JS code

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.hint.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidateForm (e) {
       //fix for hint
        setTimeout(function() 
                    { $('input').focus(); },
                500);

        return $("#contactForm").valid(); //this should prevent call of click event but I don't know why form first time is valid always :(      
    }

    jQuery(function ($) {
        var container = $("div.container"), validator;

        $(":input[data-hint-title]").hint();
        // validate the form when it is submitted
        validator = $("#contactForm").validate({
            errorContainer: container,
            errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
            wrapper: "li",
            meta: "validate",
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                address: "required",
                city: "required",
                zipcode: "required",
                country: "required",
                phone: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                confirmEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#email"
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 600
                }
            }
        });

        validator.resetForm();
    });

</script>
```

This is cut-form of HTML code

```
<form id="contactForm" action="" method="POST" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true"
 ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<fieldset>
    <div class="row justify ibChildren">
        <span>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="firstname" data-hint-title="* first name" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </span>
        <span>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lastname" data-hint-title="* last name" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />

            </span>
    </div>

        <span>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="country" data-hint-title="* country" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />

            <%--<input type="text" name="seach" value="" id="country" data-hint-title="Country" class="required" />--%></span>
    </div >
    <div class="row justify ibChildren">
        <span>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="phone" data-hint-title="* phone" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />

            <%--<input type="text" name="seach" value="" id="phone" data-hint-title="Phone" />--%></span>
        <span>
           <%-- <input type="text" name="seach" value="" id="email" data-hint-title="Email" class="required"
                type="email" />--%>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="email" data-hint-title="* email" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />

                </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify ibChildren">
        <span>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="productname" data-hint-title="product (name, shade, item #) other" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <%--<input type="text" name="seach" value="" id="productName" data-hint-title="Product Name" class="required" />--%></span>
        <span>
             <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="confirmEmail" data-hint-title="* confirm email" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" />

            <%--<input type="text" name="seach" value="" id="confirmEmail" data-hint-title="Confirm Email"
                class="required" type="email" />--%></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row full">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="message" TextMode="multiline" data-hint-title="* message" CssClass="required" ClientIDMode="Static" Columns="20" Rows="2" />
    </div>
    <div class="row submit">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
                Processing ...
            </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="requiredHint"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button id="sendMail" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit" OnClick="Send_Click" OnClientClick="ValidateForm();"  /></ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<!-- our error container -->
<div class="container" >
    <h4>There are serious errors in your form submission, please see below for details.</h4>
    <ol>
        <li><label for="<%= firstname.ClientID %>" class="error">Please enter your first name</label></li>
        ...........
        <li><label for="<%= lastname.ClientID %>" class="error">Please enter your last name</label></li>   
    </ol>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the ASP.NET validators?

Comment: I don't like them, they are not so flexible and heavy as for me

Comment: There's a `CustomValidator` which you can use to write your custom validation logic. The main problem about your code is that you would need to duplicate your validation logic (in JavaScript and at server level)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
OnClientClick="ValidateForm();"
```

by

```
OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();"
```

Comment: @cleric: does `ValidateForm` returns true the first time?